# Different Realm Configurations Appearing in Swift App

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

*Swift 3, Xcode 8, RealmSwift 2.0.2, Realm Object Server 1.0*

In my app delegate, I have a function that sets my Realm configuration to connect to a remote sync server I have set up. I'm just using a test account to authenticate until I can get the basics of sync working. `1.1.1.1` isn't my real IP address. ;)

```
let username = "test"
let password = "test"

let address = "http://1.1.1.1:9080"
let syncAddress = "realm://1.1.1.1:9080/~/myapp"

SyncUser.authenticate(with: Credential.usernamePassword(username: username, password: password, actions: []), server: URL(string: address)!, onCompletion: { user, error in
    guard let user = user else {
      fatalError(String(describing: error))
    }

    // Open Realm
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
      syncConfiguration: (user, URL(string: syncAddress)!)
    )
 })
```

This seems to work fine. I see data appear on my server, and I get no errors. **My assumption is that setting the Realm configuration here means that all instances of `Realm()` will use this configuration.**

I then set a `realm` object as a class property in two separate view controllers:

```
class TableViewControllerA: UITableViewController{
  let realm = try! Realm()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    // CORRECT: Prints "nil" as it should for a remotely synced Realm instance
    print(realm.configuration.fileURL)
  }
}
```

...and another in another file:

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController{
  let realm = try! Realm()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    // WRONG: Prints the path to the local realm file in the Simulator
    print(realm.configuration.fileURL) 
  }
}
```

As noted in the code comments above, the two instances of `realm` are different. On some of my view controllers, I can save objects to the server and see them appear on my device. On other view controllers, I don't see any data because it's using the wrong Realm database.

Can I not reliably expect a Realm configuration to persist throughout my app? Do I need to do something else to use the same configuration?

Comment: Double-check that your view controller is not being instantiated prior to where you set the default configuration.

Comment: I'm setting the default configuration in my App Delegate. Am I not guaranteed that that will happen first?

Comment: The code you posted shows that you're setting the default configuration in a callback that's invoked asynchronously after the user is authenticated.

Comment: Ah, good catch--a race condition! But I assume the config has to be in that async function since I need the `user` in order to set the configuration.

Comment: @bdash If you'd like to post your response about the async function as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. That was the issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the default configuration within the authentication completion handler. This callback is invoked asynchronously after the user has been authenticated. If an instance of one of your view controller subclasses happens to be created before the callback runs, the Realm it opens will use the *default* default configuration, prior to any changes you make in your authentication completion handler.

Comment: How would you best avoid this situation?

Comment: I have avoided it by blocking the rest of my UI with a user authentication screen. Once the user signs in, I programmatically load a different storyboard.

Comment: Funny - exactly what I have done - was wondering if anyone used a semaphore or used some other technique to wait for the completion handler to finish. Thanks!